# Change strings to make them equal

Tags: string, algorithm

Referring to question [HERE](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5683649722712064)

> We have two strings A and B with the same super set of characters. We
>   need to change these strings to obtain two equal strings. In each move
>   we can perform one of the following operations:
>
> 1- swap two consecutive characters of a string
>   2- swap the first and
>   the last characters of a string
>
> A move can be performed on either string.  What is the minimum number
>   of moves that we need in order to obtain two equal strings?  Input
>   Format and Constraints:  The first and the second line of the input
>   contains two strings A and B. It is guaranteed that the superset their
>   characters are equal.  1 <= length(A) = length(B) <= 2000  All the
>   input characters are between 'a' and 'z'

It looks like this will have to solved using dynamic programming. But I am not able to come up with equations. Some one has suggested them in answer - but it does not look all right.

```
dp[i][j] = 
Min{ 
dp[i + 1][j - 1] + 1, if str1[i] = str2[j] && str1[j] = str2[i]
dp[i + 2][j] + 1, if str1[i] = str2[i + 1] && str1[i + 1] = str2[i]
dp[i][j - 2] + 1, if str1[j] = str2[j - 1] && str1[j - 1] = str2[j]
}
In short, it's 
dp[i][j] = Min(dp[i + 1][j - 1], dp[i + 2][j], dp[i][j - 2]) + 1.
Here dp[i][j] means the number of minimum swaps needs to swap str1[i, j] to str2[i, j]. Here str1[i, j] means the substring of str1 starting from pos i to pos j :)

Here is an example like the one in the quesition,
str1 = "aab",
str2 = "baa"

dp[1][1] = 0 since str1[1] == str2[1];
dp[0][2] = str1[0 + 1][2 - 1] + 1 since str1[0] = str2[2] && str1[2] = str2[0].
```

Comment: I think it is not possible to use DP, at least with this solution, because you cant change place of last element with one element in the middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two atomic operations:

1. swap consecutive with cost 1
2. swap first and last with cost 1

One interesting fact:

1. and 2. are the same if the strings end would be attached to the strings begin (circular string)

So we can derive a more generic operation

3. move a character with cost = |from - to| (across borders)

The problem rather seems not 2-dimensional to me, or yet I cannot determine the dimensions. Take this algorithm as naive approach:

```
private static int transform(String from, String to) {
    int commonLength = to.length();
    List<Solution> worklist = new ArrayList<>();
    worklist.add(new Solution(0,from));
    while (!worklist.isEmpty()) {
        Solution item = worklist.remove(0);
        if (item.remainder.length() == 0) {
            return item.cost;
        } else {
            int toPosition = commonLength - item.remainder.length();
            char expected = to.charAt(toPosition);
            nextpos : for (int i = 0; i < item.remainder.length(); i++) {
                if (item.remainder.charAt(i) == expected) {
                    Solution nextSolution = item.moveCharToBegin(i, commonLength);
                    for (Solution solution : worklist) {
                        if (solution.remainder.equals(nextSolution.remainder)) {
                            solution.cost = Math.min(solution.cost, nextSolution.cost);
                            continue nextpos;
                        }
                    }
                    worklist.add(nextSolution);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

private static class Solution {
    public int cost;
    public String remainder;

    public Solution(int cost, String remainder) {
        this.cost = cost;
        this.remainder = remainder;
    }

    public Solution moveCharToBegin(int i, int length) {
        int costOffset = Math.min(i, length - i); //minimum of forward and backward circular move
        String newRemainder = remainder.substring(0, i) + remainder.substring(i + 1);
        return new Solution(cost + costOffset, newRemainder);
    }
}
```